# How To Perform JUnit Testing on Socket and OutputStreamWriter

Tags: java, sockets, junit, mockito, ioexception

would like to ask for help on how my unit test for a method that closes socket and outputstreamwriter will be able to pass.  For now, what my unit test was able to cover was only the part that throws Exception.

Here is the method:

```
private final void CloseConnection() {
    ErrorHandler objErrHdl = new ErrorHandler();

    try {
        out.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        objErrHdl.LogError( this.getClass().getName() , "CloseConnection" , "FAILED TO CLOSE CONNECTION" ,
                            e.toString() );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        objErrHdl.LogError( this.getClass().getName() , "CloseConnection" , "FAILED TO CLOSE CONNECTION" ,
                            e.toString() );
    }
}
```

And here is my unit test:

```
        @Test
    public void testCloseConnection() throws IOException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6668);
    Method method = Systematic.class.getDeclaredMethod("CloseConnection");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(systematic);
        clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6668);
        clientSocket.close(); 
        out.close(); 
    }

    @Test
    public void testCloseConnectionException() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException,
            IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
        Method method = Systematic.class.getDeclaredMethod("CloseConnection");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(systematic);

        clientSocket = new Socket("0", 33654);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCloseConnectionIOException() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException,
            IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {

        Method method = Systematic.class.getDeclaredMethod("CloseConnection");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Socket s =  (Socket) method.invoke(systematic);
        Mockito.when(s).thenThrow(new IOException());
    }
```

As I have said, the testCloseConnectionException of my unit test was the only successful to cover part of the CloseConnection method which I am testing.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you show how field out and clientSocket is set / created in class which contains method CloseConnection?

I also cant see how to pass value for this field from test before call private method by reflection.

Comment: the variables was set as follows:  `private Socket clientSocket = null;
 private OutputStreamWriter out = null;`

Comment: And the code i used to cover the catch exception part is this:                                                 `@Test
     public void testCloseConnectionThrowsException()    {                    
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6668);
     Method method = Systematic.class.getDeclaredMethod("CloseConnection");
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(systematic);
            clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6668);
            clientSocket.close(); 
            out.close();}`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you use not the same objects `clientSocket` and `out` in your business code and in your test.

In test you create new objects, but those is not propagate to class under test.

So it is my proposition for your test:

Class under test, similar to your:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SomeClass {

    private OutputStreamWriter out = null;
    private Socket clientSocket = null;

    private final void CloseConnection() {

        try {
            out.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And test for it

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.Socket;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeClassTest {

    @Mock
    private OutputStreamWriter out;

    @Mock
    private Socket clientSocket;

    @InjectMocks
    private SomeClass someClass;

    @Test
    public void testCloseConnection() throws Exception {

        // run test method
        Method method = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("CloseConnection");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(someClass);

        // verify if action was taken
        Mockito.verify(clientSocket).close();
        Mockito.verify(out).close();

        // and nothing else was not occurred
        Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(clientSocket, out);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCloseConnectionIOException1() throws Exception {

        // throw Exception on out.close()
        Mockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(out).close();

        // run test method
        Method method = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("CloseConnection");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(someClass);

        // out.close() was called
        Mockito.verify(out).close();
        // and nothing else on out
        Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(out);

        // no call on clientSocket - because out.close() throw Exception
        Mockito.verifyNoInteractions(clientSocket);
    }
}
```

In test we can mock java io classes, it is not necessary to test again those. We want test our application and behavior for some scenario from real world.

Comment: Hi thank you for giving a time to address my test problem.  Apparently, using your codes did not cover the part of catch IOException of the method.  That is the only part where I'm having problem to make it pass, but the try and Exception part was already covered by JUnit.

Comment: thanks for the help, I was now able to cover the whole CloseConnection method.  I just instantiated  the SomeClass in my other test case, and it did the trick.